# Nginx proxy when $http_user_agent matches mobile

Tags: nginx, proxy, user-agent

I make two version of website, one for pc while the other for mobile.

The pc version runs through django which points to a reverse_proxy through `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

While the mobile version only serves the static path in `/path/for/mobile`.

I tried many ways, for example, but cannot get it work.

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Mobile) {
        root /path/for/mobile;
    }
    else {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the docs did you read about `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempt, it turns out using extra server with fixed port number works good.

The if statement only affects a number variable, which affects the port proxy to different version of any content.

```
server {
    # static server
    listen 11112;
    root /path/to/static/html;
}

server {
    # dynamic server
    listen 11111;
    client_max_body_size 300m;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://django_devaluation:8000/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    index index.html;

    // here do the condition separation
    set $proxy_port 11111;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* mobile) {
        set $proxy_port 11112;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$proxy_port;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - If is mobile, use the default root, otherwise proxy_pass.

```
location / {
    set $mobile 0;
    root /path/for/mobile;
    if ($http_user_agent ~ Mobile) {
        set $mobile 1;
    }
    if ($mobile = 0) {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only safe operations on nginx if blocks are rewrite and return.
Try something like:

```
if ($mobile = 0) {
  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  return 200 "Desktop Version";
  break;
}
```

to verify that your $mobile variable is set correctly, then:

```
if ($mobile = 0) {
  rewrite ^ /desktopProxy/$request_uri;
}

location ~* ^/desktopProxy/(.*)$ {
  ...
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1$is_args$args;
  break;
}
```

I didn't test the "$1$is_args$args" condition, verify that before using on prod.